# "Трехмерный" map в C++

Tags: c++, map

Здравствуйте!
Возникла необходимость создать "трёхмерный" массив с двумя целочисленными и одним вещественным индексом. Я решил воспользоваться , и написал следующий код:

```
map<int, map<int, map<double, double>>> myu;
```

Теперь мне необходимо вывести этот массив на экран, вместе с его индексами. Индексы мне заранее не известны, они вычисляются в процессе выполнения программы. Поэтому мне надо вывести на экран в виде таблицы все элементы map, вместе с индексами.
Я нашел описание того, как вывести элементы двумерного map, но с трехмерным возникли сложности. Прошу вас помочь мне разобраться, или хотя бы направьте по правильному пути.

Comment: И кстати, map - это не просто массив, а ассоциативный массив, в котором элементы будут **автоматически** добавляться при обращении к несуществующему индексу. Не знаю исходной задачи, но, возможно, это не совсем тот тип контейнера который Вам нужен.

Comment: @alexolut Да, я знаю что это ассоциативный массив. Мне понадобилась структура данных, в которой индексы будут дробными, мне показалось что map подходит для этого. Или есть другие структуры, где можно использовать дробные индексы?

Comment: насколько дробные будут индексы? Если шаг одинаковый, то их лучше привести к целым и использовать обычный вектор.

Comment: @alexolut Тоже думал над этим, но индексы будут непредсказуемо дробными. В качестве индекса используется результат деления и умножения нескольких чисел, так что периода нет, и привести к целым будет невозможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void map_out(std::map<int, std::map<int, std::map<double, double>>> const &my3dmap)
{
    std::cout << "{\n";
    for (auto &table: my3dmap) {
        std::cout << "   " << table.first << " {\n";
        for (auto &row: table.second) {
            std::cout << "      " << row.first << " {\n";
            for (auto &e: row.second) {
                std::cout << "         {" << e.first << " - " << e.second << "}\n";
            }
            std::cout << "      }\n";
        }
        std::cout << "   }\n";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сработало! Буду дальше читать документацию

Comment: @АзизбекКадыров если ответ Вам понравился, голосуйте "за" (стрелки слева), если еще и подошел лучше других — ставьте зеленую галочку там же.